# Is TLS mandatory for HTTP/2?

Tags: ssl, http2

According to the [HTTP/2 spec (rfc7540)](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#TLSUsage), implementations of HTTP/2 require TLS version 1.2 or higher.

> Implementations of HTTP/2 MUST use TLS version 1.2 [TLS12] or higher
>   for HTTP/2 over TLS

However, in the [HTTP2 FAQ documentation](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption), HTTP/2 does not require encryption(e.g., TLS).

> No. After extensive discussion, the Working Group did not have
>   consensus to require the use of encryption (e.g., TLS) for the new
>   protocol.

I am little bit confused. Can you explain it to me to understand it more?

Comment: I read this as "if you're going to support HTTP/2 over TLS, you have to use TLS version 1.2 or higher".

Comment: In other words, parse it as "(Implementations of HTTP/2 MUST use TLS version 1.2 [TLS12] or higher)  for HTTP/2 over TLS"; the MUST only applies when actually using HTTP/2 over TLS.  You seem to be parsing as "Implementations of HTTP/2 MUST (use TLS version 1.2 [TLS12] or higher for HTTP/2 over TLS)" which I don't think was intended.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the kind answer. I fully understood.