# Why is Node running HTTP2 on HTTPS works whereas HTTP2 on HTTP doesn't?

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, tls1.2, http2

https version:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http2 = require('http2')
const server = http2.createSecureServer({
  allowHTTP1: true,
  key: fs.readFileSync('localhost-privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('localhost-cert.pem'),
})

server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  stream.write('Hello World!\n')
  stream.end()
})
server.listen(443)
```

running `curl -k https://localhost:443`
result: `Hello World!`

http version:

```
const http2 = require('http2')
const server = http2.createServer({allowHTTP1: true})
server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  stream.write('Hello World!\n')
  stream.end()
})
server.listen(80)
```

running `curl http://localhost:80`
result: `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`

curl version **curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0) libcurl/7.88.1 (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1t zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.4 libidn2/2.3.4 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.52.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2023-02-20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd**

node version **18.8**

Comment: if it is helpful to someone I generated the keys using `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj '/CN=localhost'   -keyout localhost-privkey.pem -out localhost-cert.pem`

Comment: Some of the links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051169/is-tls-mandatory-for-http-2) may be relevant and/or enlightening.